# How to get Eclipse External tools setup for Monkeyrunner

Tags: android, eclipse, monkeyrunner

I have started to use monkeyrunner or attempting. I have setup eclipse as described in this document http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2566234 however every time I run my script I get the following error.

Can't open specified script file
Usage: monkeyrunner [options] SCRIPT_FILE

```
-s      MonkeyServer IP Address.
-p      MonkeyServer TCP Port.
-v      MonkeyServer Logging level (ALL, FINEST, FINER, FINE, CONFIG, INFO, WARNING, SEVERE, OFF)
```

I have looked again and again and the only reason I see it not working is maybe due to my paths? If anyone has any information that could help it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get this output when **MonkeyRunner** can not find the **.py** file that you want to run.

DONT forget to add the **absolute path** of your .py file so that MonkeyRunner knows where to find it. If you dont add the absolute path, MonkeyRunner looks for that file only in the same folder that MonkeyRunner itself resides.

**EDIT:** You can copy and paste the following into the arguments field of Eclipse External Run Configurations. It will pop-up a window so that you can select what file to run. It makes life easier!

```
${file_prompt:"Choose a File":${resource_loc}}
```

Comment: I do add the absolute path as the guide indicates in eclipse for my arguments. Any other ideas? Thank you for the reply

Comment: Copy and paste this into the arguments field of Eclipse External Run Configurations `${file_prompt:"Choose a File":${resource_loc}}` So it pops-up a window so that you can choose the file you want to run. It makes things so easy that way!

Comment: Sounds great! Can you please change the status of the question as ANSWERED as well?